# Loss of text integrity in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I've got a text object on top of a solid colour, and I'm trying to cut out the text from the background image.

I outline the text and then use "Minus to Front" function on the text, and the background.

But when I do this the text quality gets compromised (see images)

Any suggestions on what's possibly doing this?

[image: This is how it looks before]

[image: This is how it looks after]

[image: This was the finished article - Need to be larger]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Looks like something to do with alignment to the pixel grid.  I can't replicate the problem, unless I scale the text quite small and specifically hit the "align selected art to pixel grid" button.

Comment: Working too small was going to be my guess, like Billy alludes to.

Comment: Ahh you're right - it's a size thing.  I've enlarged it and the problem goes.

Is there any solution?  My canvas is 22m x 22m - I'm using the design to make some wooden keyrings on a laser cutter

Any way I can maintain the text quality at such a small size?  I need the text at a 6pt size (max)...

The align to pixel grid seems to be the problem, but it seems to default to that for both the circle and outlined text when I use "Minus Front" function.  Is there a way this doesn't default occur possibly?

Comment: When creating a new document, start with one of the print document presets, then the align to pixel grid behaviour is disabled by default in the document's properties.

Comment: @HughJanus why would you have a fill for a 20mx20m piece? (or is it 20mm x 20mm?) engraving at that size would take absolutely forever.

Comment: @joojaa it's used on a laser cutting printer - and the mappings I do are by colour

Comment: @HughJanus yes but fill color, shouldn't it be by stroke color? If it is set to use stroke color then you dont need to worry about the cutting out since the stroke is separate anyway. This is more natural and way easier for the operator. Haven't seen a laser configured like yours i suppose its possible but making life much harder than it need to be. But i suppose it makes it easier to decide which side to compensate on, but again your average cad operator will be in real trouble with this since they have no fills.

Comment: Also in any case there is no guarantee that any feature you use in illustrator will work as its still not a run of the mill printer so how it interprets things is really up to the machines drivers. (jsut because it works through printer drivers does not mean it will work as a printer) PS: yeah i have about 300,000 euros worth of laser cutters at work (and yeah i manage those).

Comment: @joojaa cheers for the tips :)

You can use stroke yes - but some of my hobbies with this machine requires use of fiill - and the laser cutter I use in the workshop, and it's software, doesn't account for both types very well.

The reason I'm using a fill, is because this is the back design, the blue fill will be engraved by the cutter, omitting the white text that becomes embedded to create a raised text effect.  All the cuts and shaping of this particular design happen on a seperate SVG file, again, due to the techinical limitations of the software

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED - Software can't address fonts at such a low size being applied in the fashion we described.  It starts working at around 7pt upwards.

It was to do with the sizing - I had been concerned about this and how it played out in actual view - I've attached an image of the outcome.